# using truclient copy paste a text in javascript code

Tags: javascript, copy, paste

Actually i am using truclient in truclient I need to copy a text from my email and paste it in a text box on another page how i can perform these tasks? kindly help

I have tried simple codes given below.

```
function copy(that){
var inp =document.createElement('input');
document.body.appendChild(inp)
inp.value =that.textContent
inp.select();
document.execCommand('copy',false);
inp.remove();
}
```

and

```
function copy(that){
var inp =document.createElement('input');
document.body.appendChild(inp)
inp.value =that.textContent
inp.select();
document.execCommand('copy',false);
inp.remove();
}
```

i am expecting that a code will copy a text which i will select and paste in a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on `copy to clipboard` button to copy the text inside the `textarea`:

```js
function copyToClipboard(element) 
{
    var input = document.getElementById("content");
    var isiOSDevice = navigator.userAgent.match(/ipad|iphone/i);
    if (isiOSDevice) {
            var editable = input.contentEditable;  
            var readOnly = input.readOnly;             
            input.contentEditable = true;
            input.readOnly = false;                                         
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(input);
            var selection = window.getSelection();
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
            input.setSelectionRange(0, 999999);
            input.contentEditable = editable;
            input.readOnly = readOnly;
            document.execCommand("copy");
        } else {
            var $temp = $("<textarea>");
            $("body").append($temp);
            $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
            document.execCommand("copy");
            $temp.remove();
        }       
    $("#copy_btn").text("copied!!!");
    setTimeout(
        function() 
        {
            $("#copy_btn").text('Copy to clipboard');
        }, 2000);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="code-viewer">
      <textarea rows="10" cols="50" translate="no" id="content" name="content" readonly >Tecxt to copy</textarea> 
      <button class="btn keep-up-btn" id="copy_btn" type="button" onclick="copyToClipboard('#content')">Copy to clipboard</button>                        </div>
```

**Main part is:**

```
  var $temp = $("<textarea>"); // you have to take your input over here
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
```

Comment: Thank you so much Shivani, but i can't use Html tags , kindly tell me the code for pasting clipboard data. which i have already copied.

Comment: Thank you Shivani. really appreciate your support. lets suppose i have a text already stored in clipboard and i just need to paste it in a text box. how i can do that in java script. above codes are not working. :(